# How to control the duration of a VideoWriter function in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, video, duration, video-recording

I am using a Matlab code to record a video file using the VideoWriter function. I want to change the code to record only a certain part of the video file rather than the whole video. What command can I use to record only the first 40 secs of the data recorded at normal speed? I also want to know if there is a way I can record only a small part from the middle of the data recorded.

Comment: Do you know the interval between successive frames in your video? If so then you could easily measure how many frames are in 40s of video and set a limit for your recording.

Comment: I am using different data sets and each time it's a different frame rate/count. so i can't fix it by changing the frame rate.

Comment: Why is this question so similar to [this one you made yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739382/how-to-control-the-duration-of-a-videoreader-function-in-matlab)... Edit your question instead of copy-pasting it with little to no differences.

Comment: same project but I am having the problem in different stages of the process. First the program writes the data to a video file and then it reads and modifies it. so its not the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add conditional statements such as `if` to control the writing of the video file.

Alternatively, you can wrap the video writer function into a wrapper, which accepts your actual data, and a control boolean.

If you mean you want to record 40 seconds for each data set, with different frame rates, a wrapper function that takes frame rate and time length, and calculates the frame counts for itself may work.

If you mean you are frequently changing data sets, which will add up to one piece of video, and you want it be 40 second long, then a 'global' variable storing how many seconds you have recorded, as well as a function to calculate time increments, is needed.

---

Edited -

Based on your refined details, you may find these necessary and - hopefully - helpful.

- exact frame rate for each data set.
- a variable (should be in your controlling function/script) to store
  how many milliseconds you already have.
- a wrapper function that does the following job (and takes arguments
  accordingly):

  1. check if the current time already exceeds 40,000 milliseconds (if so, do nothing and return);
  2. calculate the time period in milliseconds of your data to be added = (num of frames to record) / (frame rate per second) * 1000;
  3. call video writer to record your data set, either frame by frame, or together in a whole;
  4. add the time period into current time.

You can make it fancier by making it able to cut a piece of data series somewhere in the middle, so for example a 10-second data won't add the extra 4 seconds, if you already have 34 seconds on file.

Comment: I mean each data set would be has a different frame rate. What syntax can I use for the wrapper function and if statement?

Comment: You need these: a) exact frame rate for each data set; b) a variable (should be in your controlling function/script) to store how many seconds you already have; c) a wrapper function that does the following job (and takes _arguments_ accordingly) - 1) check if the _current time_ already exceeds 40,000 milliseconds (if so, return); 2) calculate the time period in milliseconds of your data to be added, _frame numbers to record_ / _frame rate_ * 1000; 3) call video writer to record your _data set_, frame by frame; 4) add the time period into _current time_.